# hardware mechanisms

Tags: operating-system

The operating system requires hardware support to fulfil some of its functions.
Can you give me three examples of hardware mechanisms, which can be provided in a modern computer system to support operating system.

================== my attempt was as below:=======================
Hardaware security, hardware protection, hardware access mechanisms.

Am I right?

Comment: Can you please provide more context about what mechanisms you're talking about. Memory protection? Privileged execution? The mechanism of unboxing a new copy of Windows (the answer to which is: my fingers). There are many things in the universe that fall into the category of *mechanism* even if we constrain it to the topic of operating systems.

Comment: Have edited the question, probably it was bad phrasing

Comment: Why just "three"?? Is it homework?

Comment: If you're going to ask us to do your homework, at least ask about *programming* homework.

Answer (score 2):

Given how the question is phrased, I have a feeling this is a homework question that is being crowd-sourced.... ok, here goes...

virtual memory addressing
addressing of i/o devices
privileged instructions (ala ring0)

Comment: Thank man, its indeed revision question but was failing to get it right.

Answer (score 1):

Even though 3 things is not enough you can build a "mini-OS" with these 3 things;

- CPU Scheduling
- Dynamic Memory Allocation
- Interrupts